# selenium chrome scrape tagname value c#

Tags: c#, selenium

Im trying to scrape value of a tagname which is repeated but i need to scrape one of them. the problem is in my case both td are printed in my datagridview 
 with Name in this situation (Ayoub Zahir)
also, [+**********10](/mobile/messenger/contacts/ajax/display/?contact_id=2174360766132140)
i need only the tagname td with (ayoub zahir) to be printed.
here is how it looks like

```
<div class="_4-u3">
<table class="_4-ss">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Contact Name</th>
<th>Phone Number(s) or Email(s)</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Ayoub Zahir</td>
<td><a href="/mobile/messenger/contacts/ajax/display/?contact_id=2174360766132140" rel="async-post">+**********10</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mohamed Zahir</td>
<td><a href="/mobile/messenger/contacts/ajax/display/?contact_id=2174360442798839" rel="async-post">+**********97</a></td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

and here is my code :

```
var table = selenium1.driver().FindElement(By.TagName("tbody"));
        var rows = table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));

        foreach (var name in rows)
        {
            var rowTds = name.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));

            foreach (var td in rowTds)
            {
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
                {

                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(td.Text);
                }));
            }

        }
```

result always both td. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: could you share complete HTML and which tagname are you looking for scraping ?

Comment: @Prany i can share with you the whole class full html source too long and rest won't help you in anything, the tagname looking for scraping is the tagname <td> ayoub zahir </td>

Comment: @Prany i shared whole class html code if you can take a look again

Comment: what is the exact issue, I can see both rows get printed with relevant data. Can you add more information on what is the expected output you're seeking ?

Comment: @IlyasZahir Update the question with the information you have provided within the comments as in `<td> ... </td>`

Comment: Edited again, yeah there is two tagname named td
one with a name and second with number,
the one contains name is the one i need to be printed